# "Underfull \hbox in paragraph 58--68" warning

Tags: warnings, bad-box

I have become relatively familiar with most commands and what-not however I CANNOT seem to actually troubleshoot these darn "underfull" messages. If anyone can look at this bit of text and help me begin to understand these warnings I would greatly appreciate it.

This is lines 57-73 with the `underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 58-68` message.

```
\end{center}
    \indent\textbf{Identity Law:}\\
    If $\alpha$:A$\rightarrow$B, then\\
    I$_B\circ\alpha$=$\alpha$ and $\alpha$ $\circ$ I$_A$=$\alpha$\\
    \indent\textbf{One-to-One \& Onto functions (\& Bijections):}\\
    We say that $\alpha:A\rightarrow B$ is \textbf{1-to-1}(injective) $\iff\alpha$(a$_1$)=$\alpha$(a$_2$)$\Rightarrow$(a$_1$)=(a$_2$)\\
    \\We say that $\alpha$:A$\rightarrow$B is \textbf{onto} (surjective) if for each element in the codomain B $\exists a \in A$ such that $\alpha$(a)=b.\\
    \textbf{Bijection:} $\alpha$:A$\rightarrow$B is both 1-to-1 \& onto.\\
    \textbf{\underline{Theorem:}} A map $\alpha$:A$\rightarrow$B is a bijection if and only if there exists a map $\beta$:B$\rightarrow$A such that $\beta\alpha$=I$_A$ and $\alpha\beta$=I$_B$.\\
    \textbf{Remark:} In this event, the function $\beta$ is unique.
    \textbf{Proof:}
    \begin{center}
        Suppose B':B$\rightarrow$A is another such function.\\
        Then: B'=I$_A\circ$B'=$\beta$($\alpha$B')=$\beta\circ$I$_B$=$\beta$\\
        \textbf{Notation:} we denote the unique function $\beta$ in the theorem by a$^{-1}$, called the inverse of the bijection of $\alpha$.\\
        $\alpha^{-1}\alpha$=I$_A$ \& $\alpha\alpha^{-1}$=I$_B\square$\\
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a *full* compilable short code reproducing the message?

Comment: You need to avoid using ``\\`` to break lines into paragraph components. It should work okay by ending a line with ``\\``, but avoid using it to insert a paragraph break (a blank line) as you do in line 63. Insert a blank line in your code instead of using ``\\``. If you want the space to be bigger, you can insert a manual `\vspace` (or something similar).

Comment: First of all, try to replace the break line command ` \\ ` that you are using at the end of each line along your document by pressing instead Enter then empty space (or `\par`) for new paragraph. (Looks like i didn't notice @Werner comment :)